# bundling HTML contents for a single-page application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a single-page application. At the moment, I also have several independent pages that are built with a master page. In their markup, I have this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
     Runat="Server">
                        My HTML here
</asp:Content>
```

So for the moment, what I do is copy paste all the HTML of all the .aspx files into the asp:Content control of the one-page .aspx file. The problem is that when I change the HTML in one of the .aspx files, I need to also remember to copy paste in the single-page file. It's messy.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: A master page is at the server end anyway. Why are you copying all the content into one huge page? Separate pages with a master page will work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using user controls (.ascx) and reference then in both main page and individual page. Then you just update user control in one place.